# Pure CSS3 flipper compatibility issue

Tags: css, cross-browser

No matter what I do, I can't get this flipper to work in all browsers. For example it seems to work perfect in latest version of Mozilla and Opera. Sometimes (yepp, not always, even if I haven't changed a thing) it works in Chrome.

And of course it doesn't work in IE, no matter version.

Is this something we can fix? I've tried a lot of different things but it seems I can't get it right...

100% functionality in latest version of Chrome, Opera, Mozilla, Safari and IE 9 & IE 10 would be highly appreciated.

Demo: https://googledrive.com/host/0B3JEn2iJBANKV3piT2xRek54OWs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using cssSandpaper. It should give you support for what you need. Alternately code a version that doesn't use transforms and use modernizr to apply css for browsers that support them.

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/

Edit:

Actually for your purposes you'll want an animation polyfill. Try this one. http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/

Comment: What I want is to have a regular image (in this case round), on hover I want it to flip and show me the "backside" of the image. I'm not sure how to proceed with the information you gave me...

Comment: What you are trying to do simply isn't supported in anything below IE10. There are some work arounds as I've listed above to attempt support in IE9 and below, however they aren't without bugs. Your best bet is to design a different version for browsers that don't support transitions, and use modernizr to determine which version to  show the user.